# Android Local Unit Test returns error with a new Intent

Tags: android, testing, android-intent, mocking, mockito

I'm trying to make a simple Local Unit Test on an Android method, but when I call `new Intent ()`, it returns an error: `Method threw 'java.lang.RuntimeException' exception. Cannot evaluate android.content.Intent.toString()`

I tried to `@mock Intent intent` and also `@PrepareForTest({Intent.class})`, but I still get the same error...

Am I doing something wrong? Do I need anything else? Do I need to use Instrumented test for this?

Here's the code:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({Intent.class})
public class TimeFrameManagerTest
{

@Mock
Context mMockContext;


@Before
public void setUp ()
{

}


@Test
public void alarmSchedulePosteriorTime ()
{

    Intent intent = new Intent (); //Method threw 'java.lang.RuntimeException' exception. Cannot evaluate android.content.Intent.toString()

}


}
```

Answer (score 3):

Go to:
**Settings** -> **Build, Execution, Deployment** -> **Debugger** -> **Data Views** -> **Java** and uncheck the option ***Enable 'toString()' object view***

Comment: ohhhh mann this was the problem , thanks !!